# using JS MVC controller as a stored value, as a first class object

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

To begin this question a little differently than most SO questions, here's a working bit of code:

```
thingsToLoad: [{
  id: 'thing1',
  controller: function(el) {
    el.my_project_controller1({});
  }
}, {
  id: 'thing2',
  controller: function(el) {
    el.my_project_controller2({});
  }
}],

init: function() {
  var self = this;
  $.each(self.thingsToLoad, function(index, tool) {
    tool.controller(self.find('#'+tool.id));
  });
}
```

Figuring that, because functions are first class objects, I should be able to do this:

```
thingsToLoad: [{
  id: 'thing1',
  controller: my_project_controller1
}, {
  id: 'thing2',
  controller: my_project_controller2
}],

init: function() {
  var self = this;
  $.each(self.thingsToLoad, function(index, tool) {
    self.find('#'+tool.id).tool.controller({});
  });
}
```

However, it will stop at `thingsToLoad` at the first declaration of a controller. The error is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: my_project_controller1 is not defined` Why does this happen? I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: It sounds like you are confused about what _first class_ means.

Answer (score 1):

`el.my_project_controller1` is **not** the same as `my_project_controller1`.

The first is a property of an object, the second is a standalone variable. The error tells you everything; that variable is not defined.